# Diagnosing broken laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display

I have a laptop (Samsung NP350V5C) whose screen currently displays blank when on (either pure white or white with grey stripes). An external monitor works fine.

After getting inside, disconnecting and reconnecting the monitor cable the screen worked again. After rebooting however, the issue returned. This has proven the case on multiple occasions.

Moving the screen around while on and working doesn't seem to cause any issues, but rebooting, even without moving the screen, causes it to stop working again.

Is there a way of diagnosing for certain what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got the right process for diagnosing the issue, and you've found a potential culprit. The fact that an external monitor works tells me this is almost definitely a hardware issue. The fact that the issue is reliably reproduced on reboot could indicate a power delivery issue which in the case of a laptop monitor is handled in the same way you'd manage a data delivery issue; it's (probably) all one cable.

- I'd start with the screen ribbon cable and work your way out from there.
- Check the contacts for the ribbon cable port on the motherboard/monitor's pcb for corrosion or signs of the solder points degradation/separation.
- Start replacing things